# What is the correct way to convert from HDR to EXR without data loss?

Tags: color-reproduction, file-conversion

I purchased a pack of HDRis that are in HDR format. I want to convert them to EXR files. If I just do a "Save As" in Photoshop CC to EXR, will all data and EV information be retained? Will colors be exactly the same in the EXR? I am using these in various 3D apps for lighting. Quality is important.

Thanks!

Comment: What does exactly same color mean? Same numerical values? Same spectral distribution? Same color primaries?

Comment: Same everything. I want to make sure that I retain all exposure information, all color numerical values, and the resulting EXR looks and functions as close to identical to the HDR as possible when being used in my 3D application.

Comment: then no. Numerical values are one thing. They are ptrserved but the rest was discarded when the image was made.

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your answer, sorry. Try and view this question from the perspective of someone who is working with 3D IBL. Essentially: Will a conversion from HDR to EXR *noticeably* degrade quality? People keep telling me that EXR is a superior format hence why I want to convert.

Comment: Both formats are designed to do the same thing - preserve data that can't actually be viewed, in a file format that doesn't require it to be visually compressed onto any given display. HDR is meant to be a transitory format… recompress til it "looks nice", then save as TIFF etc. EXR is designed to be an archival format. As far as I'm aware that's the only "real" difference. Your numbers should be preserved - you won't gain any additional info of course - nor is either format directly 'viewable'.

Comment: @Jay Quality does not mean anything without specifying any qualifiers and metrics which you haven't done. Numerical values are not same thing as color, all you have is a naive guess without complementary info. So numeric values no problem assuming you save at same bit depth or higher, to evaluate the other possible quality criteria not possible to say because we do not know what your pipeline is like. Generally for all those other things the answer is: If you have to ask, then "No!".